# Drawing a circle with Pythagorean equation

Tags: c++, math, geometry, trigonometry

I HAVE to draw a circle with the following code 
(check if point is on the circle).

```
int rad=10;
// i=x,j=y
for (int j=ymid-rad;j<=ymid+rad;j++){
   for (int i=xmid-rad;i<=xmid+rad;i++){
      if (((i-xmid)*(i-xmid)+(j-ymid)*(j-ymid)) == rad*rad)
         Image1->Canvas->Pixels[i][j]=clRed;
   }
}
```

However it only draws a few points of the circle.
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: What are you expecting, and exactly what are you getting? This is all integer-based arithmetic so it won't draw a continuous circle.

Comment: easiest fix is to use (i-xmid)*(i-xmid)+(j-ymid)*(j-ymid) < rad*rad. In general, it's better to use range [r..r2] instead of just rad.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing all of this in integer arithmetic; there are [very few integer solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Distribution_of_triples) to `x^2 + y^2 == r^2` (for a fixed `r`).

I suggest using something like the [*midpoint circle algorithm*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Range based version would work like this:

```
bool RangeCheck(float val, float r1, float r2) {
   return val >= r1 && val <= r2;
}
bool Circle(float x, float y, float rad) {
   return RangeCheck(sqrtf(x*x+y*y), rad-0.8, rad+0.8);
}
bool CircleWithCenter(float x, float y, float cx, float cy, float rad) {
   x-=cx; y-=cy;
   return Circle(x,y,rad);
}
```

This kind of range is how they can draw isolines in weather forecasts, but works also for circles.

Comment: It seems like functions named `Circle` and `CircleWithCenter` should draw something, not return a bool.

Comment: teepeemm: you need to call it several times to get all pixels required for a circle.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with c++ conventions, but if I came across these functions in Java (and didn't know their definitions), I would expect them to draw something.  I would expect a `bool` function to be named `pointIsOnCircumference`.

Comment: teepeemm: circle is more like continuous data structure defined using a function. Without side effects. Note that such data structure cannot be placed to memory data structure completely without losing accuracy. Thus it needs to be a function (x,y)->bool.